# how to change the default text of buttons in JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to set the text of OK and CANCEL buttons in `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`
to my own strings.

There is a way to change the buttons' text in `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`, but I couldn't find a way to change it in `showInputDialog`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the JOptionPane.showInputDialog with custom button texts, you could extend JOptionPane:

```
public class JEnhancedOptionPane extends JOptionPane {
    public static String showInputDialog(final Object message, final Object[] options)
            throws HeadlessException {
        final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                                 OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null,
                                                 options, null);
        pane.setWantsInput(true);
        pane.setComponentOrientation((getRootFrame()).getComponentOrientation());
        pane.setMessageType(QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        pane.selectInitialValue();
        final String title = UIManager.getString("OptionPane.inputDialogTitle", null);
        final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, title);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
        final Object value = pane.getInputValue();
        return (value == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) ? null : (String) value;
    }
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
JEnhancedOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number:", new Object[]{"Yes", "No"});
```

Answer (score 20):

if you don't want it for just a single inputDialog, add these lines prior to creating dialog

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "nope");
UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "yup");
```

where 'yup' and 'nope' is the text you want displayed

Comment: And if you do happen to only want to use it for a single dialog, you can always change it back immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 14):

The code below should make a dialog appear and you can specify the button text in the `Object[]`.

```
Object[] choices = {"One", "Two"};
Object defaultChoice = choices[0];
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,
             "Select one of the values",
             "Title message",
             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
             null,
             choices,
             defaultChoice);
```

Also, make sure to look through the Java tutorials on the Oracle site. I found the solution at this link in the tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#create

Answer (score 4):

Please see [How to Make Dialogs: Customizing Button Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button).