# Customize JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How can I customize `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`? For example, I would like to change the `Yes` and `Cancel` option to `A` and `B`. Remember that it is only for `showInputDialog`

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for examples of how to customize the button text.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14408269/15935039
In your case you could do something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] choices = {"A", "B"};
    Object defaultChoice = choices[0];
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
        "Select one of the values",
        "Title message",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        choices,
        defaultChoice);
}
```

if you must use `showInputDialog` then you can do the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "A");
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "B");

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("My dialog");      
    
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.cancelButtonText", "Cancel");
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "OK");
}
```

Note that using `UIManager` will change the value for all inputs, so changing it back after your dialog is important.

Comment: ya i know for showOptionDialog but how about the showInputDialog?

Comment: @hihi I've edited my answer with a solution for `showInputDialog`